# name-based forwarding web server

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4

Hy guys,
Im currently have only one public IP , and need to serve multiple third party web applications running on different machines on a lan enviroment.
How can I forward http/s requests based on server name?
Im used to setup apache virtual hosting to serve multiple webs hosted at same server but now I need to map the requests and forward to lan machines.
Does apache provides some module to achieve this ? 
Does nginx ?
Any idea would be wellcome,
Regards.
Leandro.

Comment: What you need is a reverse proxy. Apache and nginx can do this. haproxy can as well and is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Name based http services, use a reverse proxy. Some kind of load balancer to make another connection to the backends.

With IPv6, the not enough public IPs problem goes away. IP based direct connections to web servers becomes possible again. However, solutions for IPv4 and load balancing are still needed, so reverse proxies remain ubiquitous.

Comment: thanks !! can you suggest a platform with graphic interface ?

Answer (score 0):

ok , after some tests i fugured out to make it work with nginx as reverse proxy.
Official docs were enough:
[enter link description here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/)

Regards,
Leandro